# Set editText length limitation inside tableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

I used a tableView as a registration screen and I need to enforce some length limitation to every row. I used the function below but it lets all the fields have the same constraint. Does anyone know how to handle it?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let maxLength = 12
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let newString: NSString =
        currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

Comment: Where is this code? Your cell class or your view controller?

Comment: inside view controller

Comment: What is not working? It seems fine

Comment: @TalCohen They want a different length for each each text field in each row of th e table view.

Comment: @SaikoDiabovic Why is this code in the view controller? It belongs in your custom cell class. All of the text field delegate methods should be in the class that contains the text field.

Comment: @TalCohen exactly that what i need ..

Comment: @rmaddy .. i moved the func inside the custom cell class .. but still have the same issue ,, and how to limit each row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your text field delegate methods are in the cell, the cell needs to know what length to enforce for its text field.

Your view controller needs to provide that length to each cell in `cellForRowAt` based on the current index path.

Add a `textLength` property to your cell class and then set that value as needed in `cellForRowAt`.

Then your `shouldChangeCharactersIn` in the cell class can use that `textLength` property instead of the hardcoded `12` you have now.